# Finding Files in a directory equal to 0 Powershell

Tags: powershell

I was wondering how I can display a list of empty files in a directory

```
$test = gci "C:\Users\Freedom\Documents" -Recurse 
$test | Where-Object {$_.PsISContainer} | Select-Object FullName | Where-Object  {$_.GetFiles() -eq 0}
```

I Don't understand because when I do `get-childitem | get-member`  I get a list of properties and methods I can use and in the list is `getfiles()` why can't I use this method why's it giving me an error message?

`Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'GetFiles'.`

Comment: You need to update your question to say "I also want to find empty directories, not just empty files," if that's what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I had what I wanted mixed up! And I had to add the `.count` to the `getfiles()` method

```
 $test | Where-Object {$_.PsISContainer} | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Select-Object FullName
```

Comment: Oh, you didn't bother to mention in your question that you also want to find empty directories. Hard to answer a question you didn't ask.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.Length -eq 0) }
```

If you have PowerShell 3.0 or later you can use this:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 0 }
```

Of course you can add whatever other parameters for `Get-ChildItem` that you want (`-Recurse`, etc.).

Comment: I still get errors I should be able to display a list of folders that have empty files in them I got one part to it by doing this $test | Where-Object {$_.PsISContainer} | Select-Object FullName. I don't understand how to display the folders that contain empty files equal to 0 though. I get this error  
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'GetFiles'.
At line:1 char:82

Comment: Why do you need to use the `GetFiles` method?

Comment: To find empty files within multiple directories

Comment: You don't need `GetFiles` for that. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-ChildItem` and the `File` flag, `-Recurse` is needed to get every file in the folder and in the folder below. Then get all the files were `Get-Content` returns null.

```
Get-ChildItem $YourPath -Recurse -File | Where-Object {!(Get-Content $_.Fullname)}
```

Comment: You don't need `Get-Content` (and in fact, that will be slow, particularly with large files). Just check whether the `Length` property is zero. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -File -Recurse | where Length -eq 0
```